# AS3: ExternalInterface.addCallback return false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my problem when working with flash - as3:
I have the code here and i want to known why it's value is FALSE?

```
ExternalInterface.call('console.log',"addCallback");
var wasSuccessful:Boolean = ExternalInterface.addCallback("playMusic", jsPlayMusic);
ExternalInterface.call('console.log',wasSuccessful.toString());
```

This is result in console:

```
addCallback
false
```

Thanks you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExternalInterface.addCallback() does not return a status, it returns void. So you are getting false, which is the default value of boolean data type. check this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallBack%28%29) for details on ExternalInterface.addCallBack method.